# collection, get product image

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, product-collection

Sorry for my English

I have this code

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('short_description')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id', array(12, 4))
        ->joinField(
            'qty',
            'cataloginventory/stock_item',
            'qty',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
            'left'
        )
        ->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array("gt" => 0))
        ->setPageSize(100);
```

how can i get the number of images of this product or just get the product images.  I would like to avoid the situation receiving pictures when the loop is running because it is database load

Answer (score 0):

Add just this code in your collection.

```
 ->joinField(
            'count_images',
            'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery',
            'count(value)',
            'entity_id=entity_id',
            '{{table}}.attribute_id='.$your_attribute,
             'left'
        )
```

add this code if count the amount of each product

```
->groupByAttribute('your attribute')
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a few more options

If you want main image url

```php
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach ($collection as $product) {
   var_dump($product->getImageUrl());
}
```

Or this. Or did you mean avoid doing this? Not sure. It will be extra load yes but you need the galley info so additional load is necessary.

```php
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

$backendModel = $collection->getResource()->getAttribute('media_gallery')->getBackend();

foreach($collection as $product){
    $backendModel->afterLoad($product); //adding media gallery to the product object
    var_dump($product->getData()); 
}
```